# How to check if this page is user Profile Page

Tags: 7, users

I made a custom User Panel which is similar to Wordpress Top Panel in `page.tpl.php` so this panel will be shown for every logged-in users on the top of their page. But I want to hide that panel in `user-profile.tpl.php` but, not sure is there any function like `is_profile()` or something like that so I can check for a profile page and when the statement is `true` then hide the custom User Panel on `user-profile.tpl.php`.

Note that my d7 site has its custom user profile page.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: On the block's settings you have *Pages* tab with *All pages except those listed* - why can't you just use that? PS there is no need for bold "call to arms" text, your question was just as clear without it.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my question, it should not be a `Block` i did a mistake in my Q;

Comment: Please don't use \`code marks\` for things that are not code.

Answer (score 7):

Anywhere in code, you can use code like that:

```
if (    arg(0) == 'user' // test if you are on user page
    and is_numeric(arg(1)) // and if user ID was provided and is possibly valid (a number)
    and arg(2) == FALSE // and there is no /edit or /delete added
) {
  // Do something
}
```

Substitute `'user'` with any name provided by module, if you are using alternative user profile module.

Comment: If adding this to a module, would it go in hook_init()? I absolutely hate using hook_init and am looking for a better solution if someone could recommend one.

Comment: this wrong, the path '/user/{username}' also points to the same user profile page. arg(1) won't always be numeric. Look at my answer

Comment: @SanjokGurung this answer is years old. Currently I am no longer working with Drupal, and keeping my knowledge up to date doesn't bring home the bacon, so I currently do not care. If you can improve community knowledge, great! By all means do it.

Comment: @Mołot, actually, your answer is correct , and I have to apologise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the Block configuration page. Click on 'configure block' on the contextual menu, or in blocks administration page `admin/structure/block`.

Below, under **Visibility Settings** make sure the  **All pages except those listed** is selected, and in the textarea put this line:

```
user/%
```

If you are using [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module, you may want to add also:

```
profile-name/%
```

Where the `profile-name` is the machine name of your profile type.