# Hide html / code based on content type

Tags: theming, users

I'm using a block of code that shouldn't be displayed on certain content types (not blocks, but actual code). When I use this approach, I'm getting *undefined variable* and *trying to get property of non-object* errors:

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view() ||  arg(0) == 'user') {
      $showpage = "yes";
    }
?>

<?php if (((!empty($node)) || (!empty($showpage))) && (($node->type != 'article') && ($node->type != 'basic_page'))): ?>

(Show all this)

<?php endif; ?>
```

It's the check if the visitor is on a user related page that causes the errors, but I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention of this all is to hide the main-container div on those content types. The setup I was trying was actually a bit looked too far. In fact, other pages that weren't nodes, but no views pages either (user, 404, sent-pages, module-related pages, ...) got trapped in the hidden container as well.

By breaking up the conditions (thanks for the tip @calebtr), I came up with this working solution:

```
<?php if ((!empty($node) && in_array($node->type, array('article', basic_page')))): ?>

  (Nothingness)

  <?php else: ?>

  (Show all content)

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm having no "undefined" errors so far.

Answer (score 1):

`$node` isn't available on user pages. But when `$showpage` is set, you are checking a property on the `$node` object. This gets the two errors you are describing.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you can troubleshoot by breaking out your booleans. I find it helpful to break logic onto multiple lines whenever possible, so that other people (and I) can read it later.

From:

```
if (((!empty($node)) || (!empty($showpage))) && (($node->type != 'article') && ($node->type != 'basic_page'))):
```

To:

```
if (!empty($node) || !empty($showpage)) {
  if ($node->type != 'article' && $node->type !='basic_page') {
    // do that stuff
  }
}
```

So - when `$showpage` is not empty but `$node` is, as on a user page, $node is undefined.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I think it is along the lines of "show this stuff on node pages that are not basic page and not article, or when the $showpage variable is present.

In which case:

```
if ((!empty($node) && !in_array($node->type, array('article', 'basic_page'))) || !empty($showpage))
```

Or more readably,

```
if(function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view() ||  arg(0) == 'user') {
  $showpage = 'yes';
}
elseif (!empty($node) && !in_array($node->type, array('article', 'basic_page'))) {
  $showpage = 'yes';
}

if (!empty($showpage)) {
  // do that stuff
}
```

It isn't a one-liner, but the longer code is easier to read, troubleshoot, and prevent errors.

Comment: Thanks! This is making sense to me now; I wasn't taking the fact into account that the $node is undefined on the user page (was focussing on the user-page itself).

The line `<?php if ((!empty($node) && !in_array($node->type, array('article', 'basic_page'))) || !empty($allowcontent)): ?>` does the job, combined with `if(function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view() || (arg(0) == 'user')){`  . The `!in_array` formulation looks tidier as well.

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it is working. in_array is technically slower, if it matters, but also more versatile, say, if you need to have your options populated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the user is in user page or not is as follows

```
$ARG0 = arg(0);
$ARG1 = arg(1);
if($ARG0 == "user" && is_numeric($ARG1) ){
echo "user page";
}else{
echo "not user page";
}
```

Check this link if any queries

[How to check if this page is user Profile Page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-check-if-this-page-is-user-profile-page)

Comment: Thanks, but it should be applied on all user-related pages (not profile pages specifically). Got my answer though.